# Sharepoint - JS Link - How to render search box in a custom list?

Tags: javascript, search, custom-list, jslink, client-side-rendering

I was working with JS Link in Sharepoint and managed to render a custom list. Here's a brief extract from the code:

```
context.Templates.View = RenderBodyTemplate;
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(context);
```

`RenderBodyTemplate` is a function, which will take context as its parameter and returns HTML markup as a string. Then, `RegisterTemplateOverrides` accomplishes the rendering.

So, the rendering worked fine, but then I needed a search box and search functionality for the custom list. I noticed there was a checkbox, which would display the search box for my custom list in its Properties window.

After setting the search box (this one)

[image]

visible *without a JS Link*, everything worked nicely out of the box. However, once I override the template with my custom markup using JS Link, the search box disappears. I know I'd have to render it separatedly somehow in Javascript, but how can it be done? *How can I render the search box along with my custom list rendering, so that the search functionality also works?*

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve? Do you really need to render the whole View yourself? If you only render the Items it won't 'destroy' all other default bricks of the View.

Comment: Yes, quite true. I could render the items separatedly and I actually got a little bit further. I got the header visible, but I still can't figure out how to style individual element, like Add-link and the search box. There is this function `RenderTableHeader`, but how can I style the elements? I would like to make HTML markup for these elements myself.

Comment: ClientSideRendering (CSR) (JSLink is only the technique to link a JavaScript file) is about overruling the Rendering SharePoint does. So if you replace the View with your own you destroy what SharePoint would built. Since the Search box is built Server side and then pushed to the client, there is no (SharePoint) client side code available you can use. That means you would have to built all that functionality yourself. So if you need those elements, do **not** start with creating a blank View

Comment: Note that CSR is buggy; probably one of the reasons why Microsoft ditched it, it is not available in Modern Experiences.

Comment: You can add the html of search box before the first item

Comment: @akbarali Yes, but how can I make it search for anything?

Comment: I guess it will work, you just need to add it there as static html.

Comment: @akbarali It may work, if there are proper attributes attached to it, like a proper class name and some inline Javascript and so on. Simply adding an input element there does not do anything, though. I would generate HTML for search box through JS Link, if I knew what to generate. :/

Comment: Not simple input element but the whole html of already created search box in the header of list.

Comment: @akbarali Aah, so I would see the markup of the default search box and then I would generate that onto the page? Wouldn't that be kinda hacky? There's also an ID, so if I have two lists, then I cannot use the same ID.

Comment: Yes that's what I am saying to try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To display a standard *list view control* which contains *pivot menu*, *inline search control* and etc. `RenderTableHeader` function from `sp.clienttemplates.js` is intended.

That means that when the list view template is getting rendered this way:

```
context.Templates.View = function(renderCtx) { 
    var viewHtml ='';
    //custom view rendering goes here...
    return viewHtml;  
}
```

it could be changed to:

```
context.Templates.View = function(renderCtx) { 
    var viewHtml ='';
    //render standard view header first
    viewHtml+= RenderTableHeader(renderCtx); 
    //custom view rendering goes here...
    return viewHtml;  
}
```

to get custom view rendered with standard list view header as demonstrated below.

**Example**

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {

   SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({

     Templates: {

       View: function(renderCtx) { 
         var listData = renderCtx.ListData;
         if (renderCtx.Templates.Body == '') {
             return RenderViewTemplate(renderCtx);
         }

         var viewHtml ='';
         viewHtml+= RenderTableHeader(renderCtx); //insert header 
         viewHtml += '<ul>';
         for (var idx in listData.Row) {
                var listItem = listData.Row[idx];
                viewHtml += '<li>';
                viewHtml += listItem.Title;
                viewHtml += '</li>';
         }
         viewHtml += '</ul>';
         return viewHtml;
       }
     }       

   }); 

});
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this does the trick - at least in a general sense. Similar approach would've worked for me before, had I not encountered an issue, which was totally unexpected to me. I'll elaborate on that in another answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to the question, specifically, since an answer given by [Vadim Gremyachev](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/205517/63534) is comprehensive enough, but more of a tip.

The problem with a messy markup in my custom list custom layout stemmed from the fact that I used `table`-elements in my custom markup. This causes problems, because Sharepoint inserts some attributes of its own to `table`-elements and also **changes placements of elements in the markup!** I would've never guessed that to cause problems, hence I did not bring it forth in my question.

Let me repeat: **do not use `table`-elements in custom markup for a custom list in JS Link!**

I just wanted to point this out to people, who may have encountered the same annoying problem.